# Clickable background ad with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know how to implement clickable background on current page using css and js.
I'm placing image with top center background position and making it clickable by following js:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
$(function () {
      $('body').bind('click', function (evt) {
         if(evt.target == $('body')[0]) {
              window.open('http://goto.com');
         }
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Now I would like to make one step forward and implement such an advertisement only with JS without changing any of my css styles. I know that its possible because many ad agencies are using something like this:

```
<script language='Javascript' src='//adserver.com/view.php?ad=123'></script>
```

Comment: use instead of `$('body')[0]` `document.body`. So u don't create a extra jquery object on every click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the style of an element easily with jQuery. Example:

```
$('body').css({ background-image: 'url(/img.png)' });
```

So, your code should be something like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
   $(function () {
      $('body').css( { /* SET YOUR CSS MODIFICATIONS HERE */ } );
      $('body').bind('click', function (evt) {
         if(evt.target == $('body')[0]) {
              window.open('http://goto.com');
         }
      });
    });
</script>
```